# jsMockito method invocation assertion not working as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, equality, qunit

I'm having trouble making some method invocation assertions when testing a Javascript Object with QUnit + JsMockito. The basic infrastructure is working ok: Qunit, JsHamcrest(Jsmockito dependency) and Jsmockito are properly initialized at the suite definition.

I want to assert a call to "dataStore#create" method with an object as an argument, as follows:

```
var store = {create: function(arg) {}};

test("save()", function() {
  var dataStoreMock = mock(store);

  var objectUnderTest = { value: 'aaa',
                        dataStore: dataStoreMock,
                        save: function() {this.dataStore.create({name: this.value});}}

objectUnderTest.save();
verify(dataStoreMock).create({name: 'aaa'});
});
```

I get the assertion error: "Wanted but not invoked: obj.create(equal to [object Object])"

My first suspect is that object equality isn't working as i expected, the proof is that the assertion **works** when used on calls that passes primitive data types instead of objects:

```
this.dataStore.create(this.value); //actual code
verify(dataStoreMock).create('aaa'); //test
```

I tried to use jsHamcrest 'equalTo' matcher (as exposed at jsMockito docs) without success as well :

```
verify(dataStoreMock).create(equalTo({name: 'aaa'}));
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this kind of assertion work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is checking the object itself, not its attributes, and the JsHamcrest 'equalTo' matcher does not do deep inspection of objects (it is the same as the javascript '==' operator).

You could simply check that it is an object:

```
verify(dataStoreMock).create(object());
```

or there is a JsHamcrest matcher 'hasMember', which you could use as:

```
verify(dataStoreMock).create(hasMember('name'));
```

If you're using a jshamcrest 0.6.4 or later (or the current HEAD), then you can also verify the member by passing matchers as a second argument to hasMember:

```
verify(dataStoreMock).create(hasMember('name', 'aaa'));
verify(dataStoreMock).create(hasMember('name', equalTo('aaa')));
```

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing this. Please, feel free to post an update here when this functionality is merged.

Comment: It's now available in the head of jshamcrest: https://github.com/danielfm/jshamcrest